# how assign Label for images using label propagation?

Tags: scikit-learn

I assume that some labeled data are unlabeled, which labels are set as -1.

Using Label propagation in scikit-learning leads to assign label.

```
labelpropagation.fit(x_feature,y_class) with X_feature (Color, hog, gist, sift Feature).
```

**Questions:**

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In sci-kit, the unlabelled data is indicated using the label `-1`. This may involve:

1. using actual unlabelled-data (In case of semi-supervised learning)
2. Using test/dev set of the dataset as unlabelled data. (To verify model performaces)

In either of the cases, the data is appended as part of training-set by setting the labels as `-1`.
Thus, label propagation algorithm propagates the labels from the labelled nodes to these unlabelled nodes.